# Select non text objects

Tags: adobe-illustrator, selections

I can put a rectangle around the target area, and it will select all objects,
including text

[image: all objects]

However in this case I would like to select all objects except text objects, or
perhaps select all then deselect the text objects. Does Illustrator have an
easy way to do this?

Comment: I think your best bet would be to place different type of objects on different layers...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you plan ahead you can....

- `Select > Object > Text Objects`
- `Object > Lock > Selection`
- Click-drag to select what is not locked
- When done, `Object > Unlock All` to access the text objects again.

You might also find it helpful to save a selection (`Select > Save Selection`) this will allow you to quickly re-select something.